# Transparent Upgradable Contract, logic ownership

Tags: erc-721

I created an upgradable ERC-721 smart contract with openzeppelin, initialized the initializier when deploying with hardhat:

```
const instance = await upgrades.deployProxy(contract, ["ipfs://link/", "0x7owner"], {
    initializer: "initialize",
});
```

This is what initialized in conctarct:

```
function initialize(string memory _initBaseURI, address _initOwner) public initializer {
__ERC721_init("name", "symbol");
__Ownable_init();

setUriSuffix(".json");
setUriPrefix(_initBaseURI);
setPrice(685000000000000);
setMaxSupply(3000);
setMaxMintAmount(50);
setPaused(false);
setPreSale(false);
transferOwnership(_initOwner);
_mintLoop(_initOwner, 1);
```

}

but then I saw someone claimed the logic contract because it wasnt initialized. I know this doesnt affect the main proxy contract but still worrying. It created a new collection for the claimer. Should I have initiliazed the logic contract manualy? or was there anything I should have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should have. Alternatively, OpenZeppelin has a function `_disableInitializers()` which should be placed in the constructor of the logic to disable these.

Depending on the exact contract logic, the person who took it over might have the power to selfdestruct the contract and render the proxy useless, because it would be pointing to an invalid implementation.

I suggest you redeploy and upgrade asap!

OpenZeppelin's upgrades are a horrible experience. And something like this should be prevented by default.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Yep it was easy as that: constructor() {
    _disableInitializers();
}